# PHP: download from url ( no direct link )

Tags: php, pdf, download

I want download from URL, but this URL is not direct

My code:

```
$data = $curl->Open("http://yourname.com/file/xyz","")->contents;
print_r($data);
```

After run this page, i get this errors :

````
%PDF-1.4 %���� 124 0 obj<> endobj xref 124 23 0000000016 00000 n 0000001527 00000 n 0000000756 00000 n 0000001611 00000 n 0000001744 00000 n 0000001867 00000 n 0000001944 00000 n 0000002191 00000 n 0000002456 00000 n 0000003192 00000 n 0000003699 00000 n 0000004187 00000 n 0000004329 00000 n 0000005166 00000 n 0000005313 00000 n 0000005940 00000 n 0000036025 00000 n 0000036289 00000 n 0000037197 00000 n 0000051990 00000 n 0000056578 00000 n 0000084575 00000 n 0000084845 00000 n trailer <<28b1fe3094706e478100fb6d306bd490>]>> startxref 0 %%EOF 126 0 obj<>stream x�b```"V63A��2�0pt01`^700�Zx��\�� ���y�6=Ptd�&���#x�K�E�:c���G��-B�O��8|�A|A����]܎@�7g'� �dg\*��6�Ҵ�˭���<��z��r$뺚d҂�k|����q�;�h�ܳ�MZ:�҂>�:�|���Gᬢ�g�MK�ӡ#/�.�e�t%�}�S�\�)���ҍ�8BU簥@Lꇞe�6�:�kV]yʠz��tV�li:�J�9�,g�4K�,f߹F�h�֕n���je���=�Ð� ��c��ATl�u����E%?,7N�����b˶��f/�(*��Vx�F�FGGG���;@����08&LlP�L.- ��*�(���g2 J`hwA�f��1�d``�@qB�dѰLY�s�ಬ0Yc�L}h(�Y\aBP�#�T��C�{�G �J !�fB���,[���ˀ�Va�g8����k �`=���#WxZ�+T��Q�d�b�Ty�'�:��5JKO00,YͶ�,?v���v�;z� endstream endobj 125 0 obj<> endobj 127 0 obj<> endobj 128 0 obj<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]/ExtGState<>>> endobj 129 0 obj<> endobj 130 0 obj<> endobj 131 0 obj<> endobj 132 0 obj<>stream H�T�O��0���>���I�U�@i���wc�H A${�o_��������{���d���i8�L�m��g���4�I���)����4�x ���?��h�����z����_���*�>/^oӻ���R|�?���e: �s��?~Α�q�-gn&7ۭ�ү�������L�_�G1Vq��/Q��2��U�cn%l������UYQ��ᗟV��M�nEEE��+����PT�ٗ��A�Z3]A݃�9�Z�u�� ��rl*�t����jA�CgU�J�g�f!E��U�z���
````

Comment: That looks a PDF binary. Was that the file you were looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by _"this URL is not direct"_?

Comment: @Halcyon i want download file to my server

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, this url have not extension format

Comment: That doesn't matter. What are you trying to do with the fie? Present it in the browser? Save it in the server? Force download?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, save to server

Comment: Use `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Then just do: `file_put_contents('/some/file/path/filename.pdf', $data)` instead of `print_r($data)` and you should be set.

Comment: @Halcyon HOW ?!

Comment: @Mohammad http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, download corrupt file

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, work for me

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `headers`, example for file download:

```
//assuming you are trying to download the file and not just open up a `doc` of `pdf` on your site.
$file = 'link-to-file';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to force the download using headers.  See comments in the code for more details

```
<?php

$file = 'http://pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf';
download($file);

function download($url) {
    set_time_limit(0); // Prevent timeouts
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"'); // Change the name of the downloaded file if desired
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
}

?>
```

Comment: That's ok, this is just an example.  If http://example.com/files/file routes to a file then it will still download.  If you are trying to save the file to your server then you will want to write the file instead of echo it but this is the part relevant to actually downloading.

Comment: I cant find routes path of file, i have only this url : 'http://yourname.com/file/xyz'

Comment: What is the actual url you are trying to download from?

Comment: sorry i cant send actual url. but i am sure this url use header for download of users

Comment: That's ok anyways did you try my example code?  It should work whether the file has an extension in the url or not.